# Software for creating and maintaining a board of certification

Tags: web-apps

I'm looking for a web-based software, could be SaaS, to assist with the application for a certification by a certification body.

It must provide the following functions:

1. Allow the applicant to create an account.
2. Then allow the applicant to apply for the different certification, including uploading the documentation for their education history and courses attended. They will make a payment for assessment.
3. The applicant must do a quiz after the application and payment for assessment.
4. A registrar would then approve the application - so the administrator must be able to view the application and approve the application. The registrar should also be notified via email that applications have come in.
5. Upon approval, the applicant will be notified of the level of certification they have achieved. They will then make a payment based on the level of application. Another administrator has to be notified in order to send out physical certificates.
6. The system should also track the expiry date of the certification and send notification for renewal when near expiry.
7. Renewals also require additional documentation for their continuing education. The registrar would also need to be notified for approval.
8. The software should also be able to retain the particulars of existing members and be able to display it on a website.

We've been using Moodle so far but the functions don't match. Courses as a product is not the way we want to go - the organisation checks and approves applicants for certification and not groom them. The back end of Moodle is also confusing for the registrar and applicants. Thus, if there is already a service that does something similar, I'm interested.

Comment: Some questions: 1. Is the current moodle system still available online to see? 2. How is payment currently made e.g. credit card, paypal, etc? 3. The quiz - is it multiple choice questions or something else?

Comment: Hi! I only noticed this comment now.

1. It's available at apcb.asia.
2. We used PayPal enrolment for each item.
3. The quiz is a multiple-choice quiz with randomized order of answers and hopefully randomised order of questions too.

Comment: Wow. Over a year now. I guess you have found a solution?

Comment: I haven't found an industry solution but am thinking of developing one.